# how to hide default screen of incoming call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Any one know,how to hide default screen of incoming call..??

I want to hide default screen of incoming call.

Any kind of help appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you can try below method hope it help you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not remove default screen but you can replace with your own custom screen, below is method.

your app should handles [the ACTION_ANSWER intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER), and after you can display whatever screen you like.

For your app to handle intents you have to add intent filters to the app manifest file. This is fully described in [the Intent class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Here is a quick sample on how you could handle the ACTION_ANSWER intent:

```
     <activity class=".MyCustomCallActivity"
               android:label="@string/mycustomcall_title">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />
         </intent-filter>

         ...
     </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

one option is to register broadcast receiver and set  sendorderdbroadcast having higher priority. By setting higher priority intent, your onReceive will be worked first and from there you can able to show your own custom activity.